# Split tool not splitting line as expected in ArcMap

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, editing, line, splitting

I have a long line that I would like to split. Therefore I start editing, select the line and choose the split tool. I then click where I want to divide the line. What I notice is that on some occasions what I get is not what I would like, a line divided into two segments, but I get a line split into three segments where 2 of them are connected to each other (as in the image below)

[image]

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It might be a multipart feature. Select your multipart feature, and click "Explode Multipart Feature". You can find it under `More Editing Tools → Advanced Editing → Explode Multipart Feature`

Then you can split the target line using the split tool, and merge other lines, if necessary.

Comment: Yes that was the reason, I did not know this feature existed. Thank you a lot!